# If git can figure out how to merge vertical (line) changes, why not horizontal (character) changes?

Tags: git, merge

If commit Apple puts 'a' on line 1 and commit Banana puts 'b' on line 3, git can just merge those commits together no problem, but if 'a' is at the beginning of line 1 and 'b' is at the end 9 characters across, it chokes and has no idea how to merge them and you have to do it manually.

Why can't it figure this out?

Even if the same line is edited like this:

```
original commit:       <question1 states="AZ,OH">
commit Orange line 25: <question1 states="AZ,IN,OH">
commit Pear line 25:   <question1 states="AZ,OH,TX">
```

Git merge can't figure out to put **IN** before OH and **TX** after, but I as a human can easily see how to do that, and I've used comparison editors (like KDiff3) that have pointed out for me which exact characters changed (color-coded), whereas git only shows changes by full lines.

KDiff3 example: [image: KDiff3_merge_conflict]

I just can't tell if `git` thinks OH in Orange changed to IN,OH or if it's just too much processing to check if IN was only added before OH... but maybe there's a better merge tool that can figure this out?

Comment: "Because it uses a different algorithm." - a more conservative one to force manual resolution of probably-should-be-looked-at changes. It might be more 'productive' to change the question to address a problem/goal: "How can [xyz] show an interline diff?"

Comment: (Indent by 4 spaces for a code block and add a `<!-- language: lang-none -->` comment above it for normal text.)

Comment: The main problem would be not the merging, but the UI for resolving conflicts! Demarcating conflicts with `<<<....===...>>>...` at the line level is easy enough. It would be awkward to deal with almost any conceivable notation for multiple conflict areas within lines.

Comment: Seems like only the most trivial of line changes can be merged in that way. How would you merge this: Original = "I ill go home" A = "I will go home" B = "I'm ill go home" Your output: "I'm will go home" is not a good merge. A human will need to look at that, the stuff around it, and decide what's best.

Answer (score 1):

Git's built in merge algorithm uses Git's built-in diff, which is line oriented.  It's really that simple: it sees two diffs, one of which says "replace line A with line B" and one of which says "replace line A with line C" and the two replacements differ => conflict.

If you provide a custom merge driver, you can run your own diffs and do your own merging.  It's not at all trivial, though.  In this particular case, a two-pass algorithm (first, find changed lines; second, see if changed lines can be handled as changed characters instead) might work.

Comment: Don't forget that line-based diffs are easy. A merge driver like that would likely need a fairly complex heuristic behind it to make it even halfway useful.

Comment: Oh the possibilities! If the original line is "golf", change one changes it to "wolf", change two changes it to "goof", and it merges "correctly", it'd be "woof" :)

Comment: @PaulHicks: indeed.  As an interesting aside, I actually worked on code to do something like this, inside Gosling Emacs back in the 1980s.  Gosling had already put in the classic O(n**2) dynamic programming algorithm for the line-oriented changes.  I modified it to handle a few extra cases and fancy up the cost computation to account for the ability of smarter terminals to insert or delete multiple lines and characters at a time.