# Git simple conflicts automatic resolution

Tags: git, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

According to [JetBrains IDEs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resolve-conflicts.html#vcs-resolve-conflicts) (IntelliJ Idea, etc.), **simple conflicts** means non-overlapping character changes within the same line:

> For simple conflicts (for example, if the beginning and the end of the same line have been modified in different file revisions), the Resolve simple conflicts [image: the Resolve simple conflicts button] button that allows merging the changes in one click becomes available.

The JetBrains IDE suite gives a way to solve such *simple conflicts* automatically by clicking on a *magic wand* icon, when resolving Git conflicts.

Example:

| States | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Original | This is a line that illustrate simple conflicts. |
| Change 1 | This is **a beautiful** line that illustrate simple conflicts. |
| Change 2 | This is a line to illustrate **not so** simple conflicts. |
| Final (magic wand) | This is **a beautiful** line that illustrate **not so** simple conflicts. |

Is there a way to tell Git to automatically resolve such simple conflicts?

---

To reproduce a simple conflict:

```sh
mkdir test-simple-conflicts
cd test-simple-conflicts
git init

echo "This is a line that illustrate simple conflicts." > sample.txt
git add sample.txt && git commit -m "Original"
git checkout -b change-1

echo "This is a beautiful line that illustrate simple conflicts." > sample.txt
git add sample.txt && git commit -m "Change 1"
git checkout -

echo "This is a line to illustrate not so simple conflicts." > sample.txt
git add sample.txt && git commit -m "Change 2"
git merge change-1

# The simple conflict happens here.

git merge --abort
```

Comment: "Is there a way to tell Git to automatically resolve such simple conflicts?" Makes no sense. If Git could resolve this automatically, it wouldn't be a "conflict". You can of course specify a merge conflict resolution strategy in the merge command using the `-X` option, but that is just ignoring one side.

Comment: Actually, this is not a conflict if the point of view is **character** based, not **line** based. However, there can be cases where 2 modifications on the same line don't make sense, hence the "manual" click on the magic wand in JetBrains IDEs. I understand this is not to be resolved automatically, but I didn't find a merge option to allow such resolution.

Comment: Right, as you've been told, you'd have to write your own merge driver.

Answer (score 1):

No, Git does not support such automatic functionality; its merge resolution algorithms work line-based. Maybe it *could* be solved by writing a custom merge driver, but I'm not aware of such a driver existing.

Even IntelliJ doesn't resolve such conflicts automatically, but requires you to click the icon next to each conflicting line pair.

Related: [If git can figure out how to merge vertical (line) changes, why not horizontal (character) changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986022/if-git-can-figure-out-how-to-merge-vertical-line-changes-why-not-horizontal)